# One to one relationship involving multiple tables

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design, one-to-one

Say,

I have 3 tables.

`User` which contains basic info about the users.

`SectionA` which contains more info about the user.

`SectionB` which also contains more info about the user.

There can only be one `SectionA` and `SectionB` data for each user.

My idea was to create a table design like this:

```
id  name   section_a_id   section_b_id
1   matt   1               1
```

Problem is,  `section_a_id` and `section_b_id` cannot be auto incremented since they are not primary keys.

So I tried a different approach and decided that the `id` primary key in `User` should be a foreign key that refers to `section_a_id` and section_b_id`. But I'm unable to do so since mysql will only allow a reference to one table.

So how should I approach this situation?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If it's one to one relation, it will always be easier to combine the three tables into one big table, with nullable columns for Section tables.

Some positive points I can see for this approach:

- Easier insert, update and delete operations.
- Faster data retrieval when there are less joins to use.
- Less indexes space, because you are indexing the primary key for one table instead of three tables.

Comment: I literally have around 50ish columns combined, is it good practice?

Comment: Can't see the harm, it frees you from the hassle of PK-FK constraints during insert, update and delete, and also joins when retrieving data.

Comment: Thanks for this! one last thing, when would a one-one relationship be more advantageous?

Comment: To be honest, personally I almost never use it. and whenever I do I regret it :D, but usually it's used when we have different logical entities.

Answer (score 3):

It seems you have:

- 1-n User-SectionA relation
- 1-n User-SectionB relation

so the foreign keys have to be in SectionA and SectionB tables and they have to be the User table primary key.

Answer (score 2):

> There can only be one SectionA and SectionB data for each user.

This begs the question of why you are storing the data in different tables.  That is sometimes a fine thing to do -- different users might be in different tables.

One solution is to have the primary key of `SectionA` and `SectionB` be a foreign reference to the `UserId`.  Yes, this is allowed.

Another solution is to have the `sectionA_id` and `sectionB_id` in the `users` table.  Then you can have an auto-incremented id in each of the referenced tables.

Comment: Thanks for your response! I would definitely combine the tables together; however, in what scenario would a one-to-one relationship be more advantageous?

Answer (score 1):

**Rare uses for 1:1**

- You really have too many columns;
- The table is huge and you don't want to ALTER the table to add more;
- One of the tables is mostly optional, and you use `LEFT JOIN` to get nulls.

**Righting some `AUTO_INCREMENT` misconceptions**

- The column does not have to be the `PRIMARY KEY`, nor even `UNIQUE`; it only needs to be the first column in some index.
- You do not *have to* have an `AUTO_INCREMENT` column at all.  It is often better to use a "natural" PK -- some column (or combination of columns) that is inherently `UNIQUE`.

**When building a pair of 1:1 tables, this is *one* way to do it**

1. Build the first table with a `PRIMARY KEY` that is `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
2. Build the second table with a `PRIMARY KEY` that is identical to the other, but not `AUTO_INCREMENT`.
3. When inserting a row, use `LAST_INSERT_ID()` to get the id.
4. Use that value for explicitly specifying the id for the second table.