# SQL - insert data into Parent and child table with attribute from parent table together

Tags: mysql, sql, database, database-design

I have made 2 separate tables namely userlogin and userprofile with the following columns.

```
userlogin:
    id
    uname
    pass

userprofile:
    user_id(Foreign key)
    name
    gender
    aboutme
```

Since i Will be taking some of the userprofile data at signup i was wondering what would be the best way to give the newly generated id from the userlogin table to the userprofile table.

I thought of making both insert queries right after one another but what if multiple users are signing up at the same time and one users login is saved with another users profile.

Should i instead go with saving the profiles foreign keyed with username?

Comment: Possible duplicate: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

Comment: Not likely to be a dup of that -- last_insert_id(), not FKs, seems to be the real question.

Comment: @kenfire i read it but i guess last_insert_id seemed to answer it better.Thanks anyways.

Answer (score 0):

If you worry about "simultaneous" sign up, you can use mysql transactions.

`start transaction;` then `commit;`

Example:
http://www.mysqltutorial.org/mysql-transaction.aspx

For the insertion with foreign key see this question: https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/46410/how-do-i-insert-a-row-which-contains-a-foreign-key

Answer (score 0):

Using a transaction is good, but there is probably another thing to point out here.

If `id` is `AUTO_INCREMENT`, then

1. `INSERT INTO userlogin (uname, pass) VALUES (..., ...)` -- without specifying `id`.
2. Get `LAST_INSERT_ID()` -- this gives you the value, and it is specific to your connection.  That is no other connection can sneak in and grab your id.
3. Use that value for doing `INSERT INTO userprofile (user_id, ...) VALUES ($id, ...)`

Is there some reason for not combining the two tables?  1:1 relationships are rarely useful. as discussed [*here*](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45914666/one-to-one-relationship-involving-multiple-tables) .

Comment: Great.. the last_insert_id() is just what i was looking for. I am trying to keep things a little atomic, the userlogin table will have a lot of security things such as last generated otp , acount status etc..

And the profile section is going to have more than 10 fields or so.. so i decided maybe it was better to keep the structure clean.
Thanks for the suggestion though. the last_insert_id is great will be using it on my PDO as ` $last_id = $conn->lastInsertId(); `

Comment: Good.  Each API has its own spelling for that vital function.